# Eclipse HTTP server null pointer exception

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse

i am trying to publish HTML/Ajax web page via local http server, on eclipse.

when right clicking the html page->run as->Run on server, it shows a message:

'publishing to HTTP Server at local host... has encountered a problem'

when pressing on 'details' button:

'Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException'

have anyone faced this problem before?

thank you

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.http.core.internal.HttpServerBehaviour.publishModule(HttpServerBehaviour.java:95)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModule(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1091)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModules(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1183)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:987)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)

Comment: at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Eclipse bug [405942](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405942) which is marked as fixed in Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler).

Comment: i am running on kepler 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Project is corrupted.Create new workspace it is working